# Book involving a young soldier in nanite-based armour, a space graveyard scavenger, ripped space-time, and giant manta ray-like creatures

Tags: story-identification, books

It is a book I read about 20 years ago. I remember a young soldier in a one-of-a-kind nanite-based armour, a space graveyard scavenger (who wanted to save his daughter, if I remember correctly), ripped space-time, giant manta ray-like creatures, and the space-time being repaired in the end. Any suggestions, anyone? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds pretty similar to the [Night's Dawn trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/search?q=Night%27s%20dawn) by Peter F. Hamilton:

- Young soldier in a one-of-a-kind nanite-based armor : Sounds like the SII Suit used by the protagonist in several occasions (though not one-of-a-kind, but pretty common in universe), or any of the Cosmoniks, which are cyborgs self-tailored for vacuum heavy work, or any of the mercenaries, which are again cyborgs self-tailored for specialized tactical duties.
- A space graveyard scavenger : The protagonist, which is presented as such in the Ruin Ring off Tranquility.
- Who wanted to save his daughter... : Actually his fiancée, presumed dead/possessed in the fall of Norfolk.
- Giant manta ray-like creatures : Voidhawks and Blackhawks, living spaceships used for trade and combat.
- The space-time being repaired in the end : Achieved by politely asking the Sleeping God once found, who closes the fissure between quantum domains by freeing up the stuck Ly-cilph.

As said, it is a trilogy, last volume published in 1999 if my memory serves well.

Comment: Thank you so much!